# Android onCenterProximityListener delay before triggering

Tags: android, wear-os

I've implemented OnCenterProximityListener on an extended LinearLayout and if I fling the WearableListView, when it stops, there is a short delay before triggering onCenterPosition and onNonCenterPosition.

```
public class HourListView extends LinearLayout
        implements WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener {

    public HourListView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public HourListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public HourListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private TextView mHr;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        mHr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hr);

        mHr.animate().setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                mHr.setTag(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mHr.setTag(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCenterPosition(boolean animate) {

        if (mHr.getTag() == null || (int) mHr.getTag() == 0) {
            mHr.setAlpha(1f);
            mHr.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 49, 133, 255));
        }
        if (mHr.getTag() == null) {
            mHr.animate().setDuration(0).setStartDelay(0).scaleX(1.6f).scaleY(1.6f);
        } else if ((int) mHr.getTag() == 0) {
            mHr.animate().setDuration(200).setStartDelay(0).scaleX(1.6f).scaleY(1.6f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNonCenterPosition(boolean animate) {

        if(mHr.getTag() == null || (int) mHr.getTag() == 0) {
            mHr.setAlpha(.4f);
            mHr.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        if (mHr.getTag() == null) {
            mHr.animate().setDuration(0).setStartDelay(0).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
        } else if ((int) mHr.getTag() == 0) {
            mHr.animate().setDuration(200).setStartDelay(0).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XML for the item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.daford.wearalarmlistview.HourListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</com.daford.wearalarmlistview.HourListView>
```

Here is the XML for the WearListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
        android:id="@+id/hourListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using an AnimatorListener to set and clear a Tag in the TextView because it seems like the OnCenterProximityListener is being called numerous times for the same TextView. I have tried it without the AnimatorListener and it's still the same.